# How does cloud foundry's domain and DNS domain connected?

Tags: cloud-foundry

When I read cloud foundry document about Domains, it mentions that the term of "Domain" differs from its common use and is specific to Cloud Foundry.

THen when I am using PWS, `cf domains` shows:

```
name            status   type
cfapps.io       shared
cf-tcpapps.io   shared   tcp
```

I assume the domains here are Cloud foundry domains. I can access my app by below URL:

```
https://browser-kissable-dizziness.cfapps.io
```

here "cfapps.io" I guess it's a DNS domain name because it's on the public internet.

how do the cloud foundry domain and the DNS domain name connect? or is there a connection between them? or they are just two things which have the same name?

if I want to have multiple share HTTP cloud foundry domains? I can use `cf create-shared-domain shared-domain.example.com` to create one, but how can I make it usable by public internet?

Guess I want to understand the basic knowledge about how to make a cloud foundry instance accessible from the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are two things with the same name. If you want to use `shared-domain.example.com`, you need to obtain the domain and register it yourself with a public DNS service.
You point this domain to `cfapps.io`, so your client requests are directed to the same CF load balancer and/or routers. The routers know to direct requests to that domain to your app when you have mapped a route with that domain to your app.

Comment: The common way to do this for PWS is with a CNAME record through your DNS provider.  Ex:  Setup CNAME for `www.my-super-cool-site.com` so it points to `my-super-cool-site.cfapps.io`.  You app is then running with the route `my-super-cool-site.cfapps.io` on PWS.  More in the docs here -> https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#domains-dns

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set wildcard DNS entry on your dns servers (*.yourdomain) pointing to the go-router/routers/LB VIP of them on your Cloud Foundry platform. https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/architecture/router.html

Then you can create-shared-domain and assign application routes from it.

Answer (score 0):

Admins can create an HTTP shared domain with the cf create-shared-domain command: 
$ cf create-shared-domain shared-domain.example.com

then routs can be mapped as below
$cf map-route sample-webapp example.com --hostname shared-domain --path sample1